# routerLink doesn't work in e2e test using protrator in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

I have this angular2 routerLink which allows user to navigate to editComponent by passing userId as parameter.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/edit',user._id]" (click)="returnUser(user._id)" id="redirect" class="btn" name="user-{{i}}">
    <i class="fa fa-eye fa-fw"></i>
</a>
```

I want to test this using protractor, but When I am running my e2e test.after executing click event this link is not redirecting to editComponent.

Following is my test:

```
it('should redirect to edit', () => {
element(by.id("redirect")).evaluate("user._id").then(
  function (userId) {
    browser.get('/edit/' + userId);
    browser.waitForAngular();
  }, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
});
```

Also I am getting below error:

> asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 30 seconds

what am I doing wrong here?

any inputs?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not clicking on the link actually.

```
it('should redirect to edit', () => {
      element(by.id("redirect")).evaluate("user._id").then(function (userId) {
       element(by.id("redirect")).click(); //click the edit link
       browser.waitForAngular();  //wait for page load
       expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/edit/' + userId); //if you are using jasmine framework do an ssertion with the current url
  }, function (err) {
      console.log(err);
  })
});
```

Comment: Is it clicking the link?

Comment: @Sudharshan no.. i think its because I have used icons inside the link

Comment: @Sudharshan, I have updated question details for error msg. kindly check

Answer (score -1):

1. can you try

element(by.id("redirect")).click().then(

2. also, check if u need to click on this